# using TextBoxes inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a listbox, where I'm showing a list of titles. The user clicks the row to select the item which populates more textboxes.

However, the textboxes that I'm using in each row of the listbox are not clickable - the cursor changes to the text-selection cursor.

Is there something else that I should be using?

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource products}" Width="319" x:Name="productsListBox" Height="300">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you want the text in the ListBox to be edited within the ListBox? The TextBox control is usually used to edit text values. If you just want the text displayed in the ListBox then another control like TextBlock is better. Take a look at Windows design guidelines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn688966%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I don't think it's "normal" to edit items in a ListBox directly, although it is possible. There is no true right or wrong answer but try have a reason for your choice of controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readonly TextBox in template can be replaced with TextBlock

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" BorderThickness="0"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. I tried label and wondered why it would work.

Comment: @user3791372, TextBox is supposed to be editable unlike Label and TextBlock which only present text. so TextBox needs to show selection, caret position and it handles mouse events, which prevent list item from selection